# Postfix virtual aliases end in forwarding loop

Tags: postfix, virtualhost

I am trying to get some simple virtual domain support into Postfix, by following the [README "Postfix virtual ALIAS example: separate domains, UNIX system accounts"](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#virtual_alias).

This, however, leads to a forwarding-loop, in my case. I am quite unfamiliar with all the moving parts in postfix.

```
<ber@li153-5.members.linode.com> (expanded from <ber@webschuur.com>): mail
forwarding loop for ber@li153-5.members.linode.com
```

The relevant parts from `/etc/postfix/main.cnf` are:

```
 myhostname = li153-5.members.linode.com
 mydestination = localhost li153-5.members.linode.com
 #....
 smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl
 smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain
 mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -c /etc/dovecot/conf.d/01-mail-stack-delivery.conf -m "${EXTENSION}"
 myorigin = /etc/mailname

 virtual_alias_domains = webschuur.com berk.es
 virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Then, my `/etc/postfix/virtual` file (before being compiled with postmap):

```
 testst@berk.es ber
 @berk.es     ber
 @webschuur.com ber
```

`ber` is a local user-account. Before this I simply had the domains
webschuur.com and berk.es listed under mydestination and could send
mail to ber@berk.es and have it turn up in my unix-system accounts
Maildir. I now want to introduce catchall and want to avoid mail to
ber@example.org turning up in my mailbox; when I host example.org on
this postfix too. @example.org should go to a UNIX-user exampleorg or so.

What am I doing wrong? Why does postfix find a loop when delivering to
ber@li153-5.members.linode.com? Is there maybe some part in main.cnf or postconf -d that I should provide here instead?

Comment: You don't have a ~/.forward file, right?

Comment: uuhm. I did :$. Thanks for pointing out the obvious and making me feel stupid :D

Comment: lol that's how it goes sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out to be a dangling ~/.forward file.